# Should I be using "this" or "event.target" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, this, target

I have created a simple div demonstration below, that will display none once click.

```
<div id="three" onclick="toggle2(event);return false;" style="background:#303; color:#FFF;">

function toggle2(e) {

    var textx = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;
    textx.style.display = "none";

    console.log(e.target);
}
```

my question is what is the difference if I replace

```
<div id="three" onclick="toggle2(event);return false;" style="background:#303; color:#FFF;">
```

with

```
<div id="three" onclick="toggle2(this);return false;" style="background:#303; color:#FFF;">
```

both of them work fine for my example abovee.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may well be that they are exactly the same. This depends on the HTML. In this case, `this` will *always* be the `div` element. `this` refers to the element where the event is captured. `event.target`, however, points to the element where the event originated.

If the element has no children, they will always be  the same. If, however, you had something like this:

```
<div id="three" onclick="toggle2(event);return false;" style="background:#303; color:#FFF;">
    <span>Line 1</span>
    Line 2
</div>
```

then they may be different. A click on `Line 1` will cause `event.target` to be the `span` element, so only that element will be hidden.

Unless you specifically *want* to point to the element where the event originated, it's more intuitive to use `this`.

Comment: this refers to the owner of the function. Sometimes that’s another bit of code, but it also might be an object. But if you’re writing an event handler function, you’re probably better off avoiding this? Because in IE it refers to the  event handling framework object I guess... :)

Answer (score 3):

You usually use e.target when "e" is the event like a click passed in parameter.

When you pass this as a parameter, this is the reference to the DOM node in which there is the javascript method. So here, "this" references the div.

And as you have a click event on your div, when you click on it, it is considered as an event, that's why this and e.target both work.

Moreover, "this" will always refer to you div, whereas "e.target" will reference an element you clicked in the div.

Answer (score 2):

I think isn't necessary to pass `this` as argument on onclick event, you can use `this` direct to the function.

Answer (score 2):

The **event** refers to the event currently being fired. Now in a browser the events are bubbled up from the element on which the event is fired to its parent until it reaches the document root. More at: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

In your example, the **event** points to the click event and the **event.target** is the **div** and **this** refers to the **div** itself. If you add a child element to the **div** and click on the element then the **event.target** will point to the child element and **this** will still refer to the **div**.