# Trying to understand the difference between passing 'this' vs. a reference to the event

Tags: javascript, this, dom-events

I am trying to understand the differences between passing 'this' to a function versus passing  a reference to the event itself.

I am testing with two separate divs and each has a separate function for mouseover and mouseout events. I pass just 'this' to one function and I pass both 'this' and  'e' to the other. My example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jkolden/NQvaL/13/

```
document.getElementById('output').onmouseover = function(e) {mousein(e, this);};
document.getElementById('myDiv').onmouseover = function() {mouseinAlt(this);};
```

It seems as though the 'this' keyword is always going to refer to the html element to which I attach my listener, but 'e' will refer to the child of that html element is being moused over; is that a correct statement? I'm just curious if I am understanding this properly and if my example is using these in an appropriate manner.

Comment: `e` isn't an element, it's an event. Do you mean `e.target`?

Comment: e is the event object that is attached with every event ,this refers current context

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I be using "this" or "event.target" in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060526/should-i-be-using-this-or-event-target-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the element to which you attached the event. `e` refers to the event object. Within that event object is a reference to the event's `target` (not always the same property in every browser, in IE it's `srcElement`), which is the element on which the event was dispatched.

See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target